# Will backup using rsync preserve ACLs?

Tags: 10.04, server, rsync

I am using backuppc to backup my server. The backups are done using rsyncd. Currently, I am not using ACLs, but I am think it is good to activate it to have finer control over permissions.

My question: Will backing up my files using rsync preserve the defined ACLs?

BTW, I read an [article about ACLs](http://beginlinux.com/server_training/server-managment-topics/1038-ubuntu-804-access-control-lists). They are saying that ubuntu does not support ACLs with tar. Is this real/old or not? I may not have this problem if I am using rsync. Is this right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As always when it comes to backing up stuff, do not fully trust answers from the net (like this one ;-)) and test it yourself before handling valuable data.

Taking a look at http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/rsync (and there, specifically, at [rsync_3.0.7-2ubuntu1.dsc]), we see that the maintainer writes

```
  -- Paul Slootman <paul@debian.org>  Mon, 20 Nov 2006 15:43:12 +0100

  rsync (2.6.9-1) unstable; urgency=low

  * New upstream release.
  * (from experimental version 2.6.9~pre3-1)
    Applied a mix of the patches from Martin Pitt and David H√§rdeman for
    LSBfying init script.
    closes:#375985,#385877
  * Upstream now includes the patch for replacing a dir with a symlink when
    using --delete-after.
    closes:#350522
  * Now includes the ACL patch.
```

So the package itself supports ACLs since 2006.

As for your second question: I don't know about tar, but as long as you *only* rsync your files somewhere else, you should not be affected by any possible problems with tar. rsync does not use tar during transfers.

Comment: Very good answer.