# Moving a drive preserving permissions in Linux (with ACLs)

Tags: permissions, backup, drive, acl

I need to move my drive containing only data (it does not contains any system file) from one Linux system to another Linux system.

The starting system and destination system are both Ubuntu Linux 22.04.2. But I would like to know if this is possible even accross different versions.

In the drive there are some complex file permission settings. I have 20 differnet users (no system user) who use the same drive with different kinds of permissions.

I would like to move the drive from one computer to another computer PRESERVING THE PERMISSIONS (including ACLs) AND THE USER SCHEME

I know that permission are stored in the drive but is it possible move or backup the user (excluding the systems user) scheme?

I mean for example: i have to move a drive from a pc A to pc B and the drive has some permissions (with ACLS). The user x,y,z belongs to the system A. I move the drive to B but I want keep in the system B the users x,y,z and allows (or deny) the user the access to their respective folders stored on the drive.

How can I acheive that? There is a tool to import/export the users data across systems?

Thanks

Comment: For native filesystems, the permissions are part of the filesystem and retained on whichever Linux distro and version you use them in. The problem is that tradition ermissions are usually tied to UIDs and GIDs, and not the user_names_ and group names. So you'd have to ensure that usernames are set to the same UIDs in both systems.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will backup using rsync preserve ACLs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25250/will-backup-using-rsync-preserve-acls)